# Change location of split Pane using code in WPF Xamdockmanager

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I am using Xamdockmanager provided by Infragistics. I want to change the location of split pane from bottom to the top position of another split pane using C# code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SplitPane isn't meant to be repositioned once it has been added to a xamDockManager. You would need to create a new SplitPane, add it to the target splitpane's panes collection, remove the ContentPane's from the original SplitPane's Panes collection and add the ContentPanes to the new one. If you have trouble you can try posting a sample project on the [xamDockManager forums](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/220.aspx). You could also [submit a suggestion](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Protected/RequestFeature.aspx) for adding a Move method.